# Workaround for using context ColorScheme in initState?

Tags: flutter

For my StatefulWidgets, often I could do all my subtree construction in `initSate` but for my use of `Theme.of(context).colorScheme`. So I end up constructing the widgets that rely on the context's `ColorScheme` in `build`.

In order to keep `build` as lightweight as possible I'm tempted to store a `ColorScheme` obj in global state when I start my app, and access that from `initState` instead of going through the context.

What are some drawbacks to this work around? Is there a nicer way to address this issue? Thanks!

e.g. Code like this will throw an exception when `Example` is constructed.

(This is a trivial example but if `_body` was an expensive widget, constructing it `initState` would be better than constructing it in `build`.)

> dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedTheme>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _ExampleState.initState() completed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  late final Widget _body;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _body = Text(
      'Hi',
      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => _body;
}
```

One possible solution is this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  late final Widget _body;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _body = _MyText();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => _body;
}

class _MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Hi',
      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess another approach would be to create a small private Widget class for each part of the sub-tree that uses `Theme.of(context).colorScheme`.

Comment: What do you mean by doing subtree construction in `initState`? Can you give the example? Also what issue are you facing when you let `ColorScheme` being accessed through the context?

Comment: If you have an expensive widget, then split the subtrees into separate widgets and make use of the `const` constructor. That way, whenever the `build` method gets called again, only the necessary changes are rebuilt. The constant widgets that are not affected will not be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`didChangeDependencies`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) instead.

Citing `initState` docs:

> You should not use [`BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html) from this method. However, [`didChangeDependencies`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) will be called immediately following this method, and [`BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html) can be used there.

`didChangeDependencies` is called right after the `initState` on the first build and when any of the widget's dependencies (inherited widgets, like `Theme`) notify. You have access to `context` there.